# Socket handle leak detected on instance on Azure WebApp

Tags: c#, azure, azure-web-app-service

I have been stuck on one issue. I am getting the following error message:

> Unable to connect to the remote server. An attempt was made to access
>   a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions

After searching on the web and taking help of Azure support, I came to know that if Web App reaches outbound connection limit of azure web app instance, it refuses connections or kill extra connections. Here is the image of open socket :

[image]

My application calls third-party WebAPI and WCF service. I have written code to close connections after making a call to APIs. but it doesn't work for me. I did following code to call Web API.

```
var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("www.xyz.com");
request.Method = "POST";
request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
request.KeepAlive = false;
request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Handshake");
byte[] bodyData;
bodyData = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(input_data);
request.ContentLength = bodyData.Length;
request.GetRequestStream().Write(bodyData, 0, bodyData.Length);
request.GetRequestStream().Flush();
request.GetRequestStream().Close();

using (var response = request.GetResponse())
{
    using (var reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream(), Encoding.UTF8))
    {
       string output_data = reader.ReadToEnd();
    }   

    response.Close();   
}
```

Could anyone guide me how to get rid of this issue?

Comment: I'd start with `using (var requestStream = request.GetRequestStream()) {...}`, instead of calling `GetRequestStream()` 3 times

Comment: why do you call request.GetRequestStream().Close() ?   response.Close() will close the socket.

Comment: Why request.KeepAlive = false ?  try to set it to true

Comment: @FabrizioAccatino, request.KeepAlive = false. this is coming as true by default and it was there before I set it false.

Comment: @FabrizioAccatino, How could I check if the socket is closed or not?